# OpenLayers ArcGIS93Rest symbol size

Tags: openlayers-2, web-service

I'm using OpenLayers 2 to display ESRI WMS data ([ArcGIS93Rest layers](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/ArcGIS93Rest-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.ArcGIS93Rest.OpenLayers.Layer.ArcGIS93Rest)).

The data I'm displaying contains symbols (and sometimes labels) and I'd like to increase the display size of these symbols (and corresponding labels).

An example of the data being displayed can be found [here](http://ofr.marineplanner.io/explore/arcrest_example/outfall-locations).

And the web service for that data can be found [here](http://ocean.floridamarine.org/arcgis/rest/services/Projects_Other/OFR_Vector/MapServer/42).

Is it possible to adjust the symbol/label size on my end?
Or am I stuck with the symbol size provided by ArcServer?

Answer (score -1):

ArcGIS93Rest is for an ESRI export service (note MapServer/export).  You are using an ESRI Feature service.  You could obtain the meta data and use the query service to roll your own feature layer solution.

OBTAIN META DATA

> http://ocean.floridamarine.org/arcgis/rest/services/Projects_Other/OFR_Vector/MapServer/42?f=pjson

QUERY FOR FEATURES

> http://ocean.floridamarine.org/arcgis/rest/services/Projects_Other/OFR_Vector/MapServer/42/query

A simpler approach might be to publish this service as WFS and define all the styling yourself (via a [symbolizer](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/symbolizers-fill-stroke-graphic.html)) and use an [OpenLayers WFS layer](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/examples/wfs-states.html).

Comment: Thanks @ca0v, I'm not able to publish the service myself.  I am currently using the export service.  Are you suggesting I use the feature service instead?  (Implying I would then have control over styling the features myself.)

Comment: My mistake; I didn't see the export link and assumed it was a feature service.  But yes, that is what I was suggesting.  The export service will only produce imagery; I believe you want to control how these point features are rendered so do that with a symbolizer.